# Am I allowed to upload Winter Bash-related content on personal sites?

Tags: support, winter-bash, licensing, copyright

As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320304/does-stack-exchange-own-the-copyright-of-winter-bash-hats), Stack Exchange owns the copyright to all WB hats and WB-related content.

However, I am wondering if I can upload images of hats onto a public-facing personal site to make some sort of a gallery of past WB hats and maybe include some past and present WB site styling or even the knitting tool there for indefinite fun. (Just to be clear, such a site will **distinctly state its status as a fan site and attribute its content to SE**.)

Also, I recognise that SE logos [can't be used on third-party sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo), but can WB logos be used for such a fan site?

In the past, an SE employee allowed the usage of WB hats as ["[one] sees fit"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312528/what-license-are-the-hats-published-on/312546#312546) so I just want to check if that is still the case for *non-commercial* fan projects.

<sup>(I haven't started work on such a site or anything like that; just thought I'd check first.)</sup>

> **Note regarding the (previously marked) [duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212828/can-i-download-the-winter-bash-hats-for-use-as-profile-picture):**
>
> The marked duplicate is **narrower as it specifically relates to hats**, I am trying to ask about the usage of other WB content, such as the [snowflakes animation on the WB2013 site](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/14/winter-bash-2013) and also the knitting editor on the WB2017&18 site.
>
> But, I reiterate that all WB-related content (hats, styling, knitting editor, etc.) used will be **clearly attributed to SE**, on such a fan site if I decide to create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can use the WB content for **private, noncommercial** use, more info below.

Since your fan site, is not used to make profit, it's considered noncommercial and you can therefore use the WB content without permission on your site.

---

You can use WB graphics as well as all other graphics on SE for 'personal, noncommercial' use only.

### Terms of Service

Here is a short version of the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> The Network and its contents are intended solely for the use of the Network Subscribers and may only be used in accordance with the terms of this Agreement. All materials displayed or performed on the Network, including, but not limited to text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and animations (collectively, “Content”) (other than Content posted by Subscriber (“Subscriber Content”)) are the property of Stack Exchange and/or third parties and are protected by United States and international copyright laws.
>
> [...]
>
> Subscriber shall abide by all copyright notices, information, and restrictions contained in any Content accessed through the Services.
>
> [...]
>
> Other than as expressly set forth in this Agreement, Subscriber may not copy, modify, publish, transmit, upload, participate in the transfer or sale of, reproduce (except as provided in this Section), create derivative works based on, distribute, perform, display, or in any way exploit, any of the Content, software, materials, or Services in whole or in part.
>
> Subscriber may download or copy the Content, and other items displayed on the Network for download, for personal use, provided that Subscriber maintains all copyright and other notices contained in such Content.
>
> [...]
>
> Any other downloading, copying, or storing any Content for other than personal, noncommercial use is expressly prohibited without prior written permission from Stack Exchange, or from the copyright holder identified in such Content's copyright notice.

### Can I Download Them?

The above license is very clear on what you are allowed to do:

> Any other downloading, copying, or storing any Content for other than **personal, noncommercial** use is expressly prohibited without prior written permission from Stack Exchange, or from the copyright holder identified in such Content's copyright notice.

Without their permission, you can download, copy, or store the content for **personal, noncommercial** use.